# Adding printlines and text to FileWriter (writer.write)

Tags: java, output, try-catch, filewriter

I was wondering how to add print lines to a filewriter output.
At the moment when the full code has run and I open the .txt folder it looks like this

https://gyazo.com/b287d61eafb100dce1ce2476b71623e9

I was wondering how I could add text and printlines to make the format similar to this : https://i.gyazo.com/def6e157e24dc0ed0fe68e1509152405.png

```
   try
    {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Gamer Report Data.txt");
        writer.write(gamerName);
        writer.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator"));
        writer.write(gamerReport);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("File does not exist!");
    }

    }
```

Comment: Why not use a [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)?

Comment: You output that format by actually writing that text. Wrapping the `FileWriter` with a `PrintWriter` makes it a lot easier, but is not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
 try
    {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Gamer Report Data.txt");
        writer.println("Player: " + gamerName);
        writer.println();
        writer.println("-------------------------------");
        //This line will split the gameReport string by the ':' separator
        //Into an array of strings.
        string[] report = gameReport.split(":");
        //Edit here with regards to latest comment
        //This will print the game score if the reports array has data.
        if(report == null) {
            writer.println("Game report was null.");
        } else if(report.length == 3) {
            writer.println("Game:" + report[0]+", score=" + report[1] +", minutes played="+ report[2]);
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("File does not exist!");
    }

    }
```

Comment: This seemed to work however returned this error  https://i.gyazo.com/030ecc647821324718af313164b8a213.png

Comment: oh you can add a little conditional in there to fix this. So this happens when you get an array that is empty or contains less than 3 items. So just at the line `writer.println("Game:" + ", score=" +report[0] +", minutes played="+ report[1] + report[2]);` do an `if(report.length > 0) ` this will ensure that the `report` array is not empty. Sorry I never really tested this I am just going from memory its been a while since I did any real java development. This is a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: Oh there is a small error in the code, sorry use ":" not ':', using single quotes will be a character value. See the changed code above.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want? just similar to second picture.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

//if your java file name is ABC.java then your class name is ABC
public class ABC
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        String text  = "Name here";
        String text2 = "Data here"; 

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Output.txt");
        fw.write(text);
        fw.write(System.lineSeparator());
        if(text.length()>text2.length())
            for(int i=0;i<text.length();i++) fw.write("-");
        else
            for(int i=0;i<text2.length();i++) fw.write("-");      
        fw.write(System.lineSeparator());
        fw.write(text2);
        fw.close();
    }    
}
```

Comment: This worked however seemed to return the error https://i.gyazo.com/80a4bf240c34ae0e30639926f7bd232a.png

Comment: will, seems you just copy it into IDE, I didn't see Class in the picture.

Comment: OK, here is the complete code.
Make sure, you copy and use it in correct way.
the import java.io.FileWriter is necessary.

Comment: Sorry was my mistake very new to programming. Thank-you very much